# Spring / EJB3.1 JNDI multiple-ear problems

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

I have 2 deployables:

First, my entity layer, which is an EAR file packaging an EJB.
JBoss EAP 6.2 says it's all good, and provides these JNDI names:

```
java:global/entityLayerEar-1.0/entity-service/TestDao!com.test.dao.TestDao
java:app/entity-service/TestDao!com.test.dao.TestDao
java:module/TestDao!com.test.dao.TestDao
java:jboss/exported/entityLayerEar-1.0/entity-service/TestDao!com.test.dao.TestDao
java:global/entityLayerEar-1.0/entity-service/TestDao
java:app/entity-service/TestDao
java:module/TestDao
```

Second, my application layer, which is a WAR file containing an EJB.  It too gets its JNDI names.

```
java:global/application/RequestHandler!com.test.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:app/application/RequestHandler!com.test.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:module/RequestHandler!com.test.application.RequestHandlerInterface
java:global/application/RequestHandler
java:app/application/RequestHandler
java:module/RequestHandler
```

Now I'm just trying to get my TestDao EJB injected in my RequestHandler.  Is that too much to ask?

I first tried with @Local, and @EJB wouldn't find it.  I then tried JNDI lookup on "new InitialContext()", and got:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.dao.TestDao$$$view2 cannot be cast to com.test.dao.TestDao
```

I couldn't work this out.  I presumed JBoss EAP 6.2 just doesn't support injecting local beans from other EARs.

So I tried @Remote:

```
@Remote 
public interface TestDao {...}
```

and

```
@Stateless(name="TestDao") 
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {...}
```

But in my RequestHandler class,

```
@EJB
private TestDao testDao;
```

will not find it.  It gets:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.test.dao.TestDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.ejb.EJB(beanName=, mappedName=, beanInterface=class java.lang.Object, description=, name=, lookup=)}
```

I've tried @EJB(name="TestDao"), @EJB(lookup="TestDao"), etc.

So I figured, alright, lose the @EJB and let's find it with JNDI.

If I just have

```
jndiContext = new InitialContext();
```

I can run through the tree, and it finds the JNDI names, but complains "javax.naming.NotContextException" for each one.  Trying to get the beans out cause "java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.naming.InitialContext"

I tried using the JNDI connection props suggested by this [EJB Remoting](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project) link... and

```
 testDao = (TestDao)jndiContext.lookup("java:global/entityLayerEar-1.0/entity-service/TestDao");
```

but I get:

```
Could not load JNDI context: : javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.application.war:main" from Service Module Loader
```

It's getting pretty frustrating.  Anyone have any ideas?  I would prefer Local beans, but I'll take anything at this stage.

Comment: Why are you using two EAR files?

Comment: I had it all in one WAR to start with, working great, but have redesigned it to separate the entity layer.  That way, I can write other apps that re-use the same Daos, instead of having every application making their own version.

Comment: You can deploy multiple WAR files within the same EAR

Comment: Sure, but if I bundle my entity layer in the same EAR as my app, then I am coupling the two.  App#2 will need App#1 deployed if it wants to use the entity layer.

Comment: I know where you're trying to go with this, but I'm not sure the additional complexity is worth it. FWIW, did you try @EJB(lookup="java:global/entityLayerEar-1.0/entity-service/TestDao!com.test.dao.TestDao")?

Comment: let's see... yeah nope "No matching bean..."  Ok, well I'll try out rearranging it all into one EAR.  Be back in a bit, thanks

Comment: Hoo boy... well I rearranged it all, worked out the skinny war stuff, so now there's an EAR with a WAR, an EJB JAR, a lib folder, and a META-INF folder...  and am still getting "No matching bean of type...found".

Comment: Ok, well I can look it up by JNDI name at least!  Good enough!  Really weird though that @EJB doesn't work tho.

Comment: That "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException" makes me wonder if it is the Spring Framework with the problem. Are you using @EJB on any beans with a lifecycle controlled by Spring?

Comment: Yeah, I've probably mixed CDI and Spring incorrectly.  Spring loads the RequestHandler, but the TestDao bean is presumably loaded with @javax.ejb.Stateless, after Spring saying to context:component-scan the folders.  But I can never find good up-to-date documentation on the combo, so I don't know what I've messed up specifically.